# Gmaps4rails : How to change appearance of marker when user clicks link in sidebar?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to get this behavior with gmaps4rails :
User clicks link in the sidebar, corresponding marker on the map changes image/color in order to make the selected one stand out from the others.

I've tried with this code

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
        var len = Gmaps.map.markers.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', (function(i){
                return function(){
                    console.log($(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject.ne.ga).attr("src", "/assets/marker_sprite2.png"));
                }
            })(i));
        }
    }
```

But this changes every marker's appearance, which is not very useful for what I'm trying to do !

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

EDIT : Made it work see answer below

EDIT 2 : While this solution worked for what I wanted, I stumbled upon an other issue with this method, see comment to answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a javascript issue. Actually, you can't make a closure with a changing counter: it will always be referenced with it's last value.

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++){
    marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', 
      (function(marker){
        return function(){
         console.log($(marker.serviceObject.ne.ga).attr("src", "/assets/marker_sprite2.png"));
        }
      })(marker)
    )
  }
}
```

Your main issue is a bit long, not complex but long. The idea is the following:

- add an `id` to each marker, you could use the block argument of the `to_gmaps4rails` method and add some more json
- create the sidebar yourself and add the id to each line to know which marker you want when you click the li
- loop all markers to get the one with the proper id
- change it's picture

Comment: Well it turns out I didn't need to add an id, I managed to make it work with the callback function, see my edited post

Comment: Good, but stack overflow rule is one question at a time

Comment: Btw, I can't see te relatioship with the sidebar in your code

Comment: Well the relationship is the m variable I pass in the closure, whenever the click is made (whether in sidebar or on the map), I reset all markers to normal and then change the one that should be standing out by calling setIcon on my m variable with the clicked marker in it. It's not all clear to me either as I just found out about the closure technique :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this code :

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function(e){
        var len = Gmaps.map.markers.length;
        var markers = Gmaps.map.markers;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            m = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(m.serviceObject, 'click',
                (function(m, markers){
                    return function(){
                        for(a in markers){
                            markers[a].serviceObject.setIcon("/assets/marker_sprite.png");
                        }
                        m.serviceObject.setIcon("/assets/marker_sprite2.png");
                    }
                }(m, markers))
            )
        }
    }
```

What's happening is we add a click listener to each marker and pass to this listener function the marker itself. I also pass in the whole markers array to reset them all on each click and then make the one I'm interested stand out. This is the simple version, my final version gives this :

```
 Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
        var len = Gmaps.map.markers.length;
        var markers = Gmaps.map.markers;
        var anchor = new google.maps.Point(9.5, 34);
        var sAnchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 34);
        var origin = new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
        var sOrigin = new google.maps.Point(28.5, 0);
        var size = new google.maps.Size(28.5,34);

        var markerNormal = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/assets/marker_sprite.png", size, origin, anchor);
        var markerHighlight = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/assets/marker_sprite_bleu.png", size, origin, anchor);
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/assets/marker_sprite.png", size, sOrigin, sAnchor);
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            m = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
            google.maps.event.addListener(m.serviceObject, 'click',
                (function(m, markers){
                    return function(){
                        console.log(m);
                        for(a in markers){
                            markers[a].serviceObject.setIcon(markerNormal);
                            markers[a].serviceObject.setZIndex(1);
                            markers[a].serviceObject.shadow = shadow;
                        }
                        Gmaps.map.map.setZoom(7);
                        m.serviceObject.setZIndex(99);
                        m.serviceObject.setIcon(markerHighlight);
                    }
                }(m, markers))
            )
        }
    }
```

If you see anything that could be improved feel free to comment :)

Comment: Well in the end I still had to fall back to apneadiving's answer because automatic generation is done through JS. As a result, I could not interact with my markers list because when the document was loaded, the list was not. Also it was bad for SEO and looked kind of ugly in the source of the page