# Gmaps4rails highlight current marker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I want to show several Shops "nearby" the main Shop that the user is currently looking at. 
The markers have a different picture which is implemented via the `marker_picture` method in the Shop class. Now I want to use a bigger marker image for the "current" Shop - **How should I do this?**

It seems that gmaps4rails gem assumes that the same picture should be used each time for the same object.

(An example: We have two Stores, Store_A and Store_B. In the view "show" Store_A, Store_A should have the picture "accepts_credit_card_big.png", Store_B "only_cash_small.png"; on the other hand when I am accessing the page for Store_B, it should be the picture "accepts_credit_card_small.png for Shop_A and "only_cash_big.png" for Shop_B. 
I hope this makes clearer what I want)

Comment: Have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371335/gmaps4rails-how-to-change-appearance-of-marker-when-user-clicks-link-in-sideba

Comment: why dont you just change the json of the markers? cant see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with Javascript manipulation, this also seems to be the suggested way (see comment)